# Kinect + Udoo Quad?

Tags: robotic-arm, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wondering if it would be possible to get Kinect to work with Udoo board (Quad).  I have found that there is now support for [ROS+Udoo](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UDOO). Also saw a question asked about [Xtion + Udoo](http://answers.ros.org/question/113131/can-use-freenect-library-for-asus-xtion/) but it would really be great if it could be possible for Kinect+Udoo. I wish someone could give some insights on this matter. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114241/kinect-+-udoo-quad?/) by [Kalmah](https://answers.ros.org/users/10371/kalmah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-01-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the Xtion works, the Kinect will probably work as well.

Most of the ARM boards I've seen aren't quite powerful enough to handle the bandwidth of the Kinect, but I think the i.MX6 in the Udoo can probably handle it. I think it's worth a try.

If you do give it a try, please let me know how it goes.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kalmah](https://answers.ros.org/users/10371/kalmah/) on 2014-01-02**:
Thanks, I will take a look at workarounds done for Beagleboard and RaspberryPi and see if similar steps would apply for Udoo. But looking at the complexity, it would've been great if someone experienced could tackle this challenge.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-02**:
The combination of ROS+Kinect experience and ownership of an Udoo board will be difficult to find. I could probably come up with an answer in half a day if I had an Udoo, but I don't have the money or the time to experiment with all of the ARM boards on the market.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-02**:
For a start, I would try to install the ros-hydro-openni-camera package and see if it works.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2014-01-08**:
Small addition: According to an embedded board developer the USB controllers on those ARM boards are often another limiting factor. E.g. on some boards the same controller is in charge of handling both Ethernet and USB connections, what can significantly lowers the available bandwidth.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-09**:
The Freescale i.MX6 has separate USB and gigabit ethernet controllers on-chip, so it should be more capable of high-bandwidth USB than most ARM boards. Udoo block diagram: http://www.udoo.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/UDOO_Block_Diagram_rel_1_1.pdf